# Can I Use Jenkins to deploy Hyperledger Fabric Chaincode?

Tags: jenkins, hyperledger-fabric, chaincode

Dear Community / Support,

I'm new to Jenkins. I would like to ask is there possible for me to deploy Hyperledger Fabric Chaincode using Jenkins?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chaincode as service, then it becomes very easy to deploy the chaincode and upgrade it. You need to package the chaincode in the form of container image and run the install command.

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply. Based on your answer, you are referring to Docker Compose and not Jenkins?